# vscode/Python | unable to acess environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

So basically my issue is that I have no idea why I can't access the environment variables that I have set in my .env file. I'm pretty sure I have set it up correctly because AERPL produces the correct output, but when I use my terminal (Git-bash) or code runner, they can't access the environment variables and just spit out an error. I have done a lot of searching online, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it isn't working. I'm sure there is some easy fix that I am somehow missing... But if anyone can figure out why it isn't working, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

---

**File Structure**

```
cwd/
    .vscode/
        settings.json
    env/
        Lib/
        Scripts/
        .env
    testenv.py
```

**settings.json**

```
{
    "python.testing.promptToConfigure": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe", // Python 3.8.2
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}\\env\\.env",
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
    },
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true
}
```

**.env**

```
TEST = "test"
```

**testenv.py**

```
import os
print(os.getenv('TEST'))
print("==========")
print(os.environ['TEST'])
```

**Code Runner/Integrated Terminal Output:**

```
os.getenv: None
==========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\test\testenv.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(f"os.environ: {os.environ['TEST']}")
  File "c:\python38\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TEST'

$ py testenv.py
os.getenv: None
==========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testenv.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(f"os.environ: {os.environ['TEST']}")
  File "c:\python38\lib\os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TEST'
```

**AEREPL Output**

```
Print Output:
os.getenv: test
==========
os.environ: test
Variables:
{}
```

Comment: VS Code will not add them to your terminal nor will it add them when you "run" (i.e. the play button) your program. It will, however, load it if you use the VS Code "launcher" (e.g. if you launch a debug run with F5). I don't really know the typical VS Code workflow, but if you want them in your integrated terminal you'll need to treat it more like just a terminal that doesn't know about these environment settings.

Comment: @alkasm, this seems to have worked haha, thank you. I know this wasn't really that complicated but I was just stumped. Nonetheless thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may force to recognize environment varibles in integrated terminal by VSCode without entering to debug mode. This example is for Linux and bash.

- Find parameter `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux`
- Add to settings.json, correct paths to actual .env file and shell:

```
        "bash-env": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "args": ["-c", "if [ -f .env ]; then export $(cat .env); fi; if [ -f .vscode/.env ]; then export $(cat .vscode/.env); fi; bash"]
        },
```

- Find parameter `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux`
- Choose profile `bash-env`

This example is inspired by [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/944)